# Why can I simplify this integral?

Tags: calculus, integration

In my textbook I have a problem which uses the [WKB approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WKB_approximation) applied to the Coulomb potential. This approximation gives that

$$\int^{r_2}_{r_1}dr\frac{1}{r}\sqrt{-r^2-ar+b}=(n+1/2)\pi\hbar$$

but the LHS of this integral is simplified immediately to

$$\int^{r_2}_{r_1}dr\frac{1}{r}\sqrt{(r-r_1)(r_2-r)}$$

so that the following identity can be used on it:

$$\int^{r_2}_{r_1}dr\frac{1}{r}\sqrt{(r-r_1)(r_2-r)}=\frac{\pi}{2}(\sqrt{r_2}-\sqrt{r_1})^2$$

What is the theorem that allows the simplification to the form which has its limits as the roots?

Comment: Some conditions for $a,b$? In general, every quadratic has two, possibly complex or identical, roots $r_1,r_2$.

Comment: @ΒασίληςΜάρκος no conditions are given other than that the result does not depend on r

Comment: With $r$ being real or complex?

Comment: @ΒασίληςΜάρκος real in this case but this is a physics problem so I'm not sure it is always real

Comment: Being complex is the case @Artificial Intelligence has included in his answer. In the case $r$ is real, then note that: $$\Delta=a^2+4b$$ and it is sufficient, for instance, for $b\geq0$ to have two real roots. Since it is a physics problem, does it happen that this is a restrictin the nature of the problem imposes?

Comment: From where does $\pi$ come into picture? I think you should provide more context

Comment: The result shouldn't depend on $r$, that's something one can see immediately from the definition of definite integrals without even looking at what the integrand is (just the $dr$).

Comment: @samjoe i have now updated the question

Comment: There is a hidden connection between the variables $r_1$, $r_2$, $a$, $b$. Furthermore the $\hbar$ here is pure magic. Check your source!

Answer (score 1):

$$-r^2 - ar + b$$

Is a second degree polynomial, which thence possesses two roots (either real or complex conjugate).

The roots are found to be

$$r_{1,\ 2} = \frac{a \pm \sqrt{a^2 + 4b}}{-2} = \frac{-a\pm\sqrt{a^2 + 4b}}{2}$$

Hence you can write your polynomial as

$$(r - r_1)(r_2 - r)$$

Comment: r1 and r2 are also the limits in this case

Comment: it is the Theorem of VIETA, the same as i have written

Comment: @Cameron That is a mere "coincidence", limits doesn't change or alter the integral, as long as you don't perform substitutions, which is not the case.

Comment: Cameron - Note that expression inside square root is always positive for $r\in (r_1, r_2)$